# Convex and Concave lenses

Tags: optics, lenses

Why does concave lens diverge light even though it seems pointing towards 2F and why does convex lens converge light even though it is bulged out? (The lenses are same shape on both sides here)

Comment: What do you mean?  Please add details and a diagram

Comment: A convex lens is bulged outwards so shouldn't it send light outwards instead of converging it at one point?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The convex lens converges light because near the points at the top and bottom it acts like a prism

[image]

but in the middle the lens has parallel sides and the light passes through without much refraction.